# C# List is adding incorrect members

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to add a few different members to a list, but when the list is added to it contains copies of only the last member added:

```
    private PotentialSolution tryFirstTrack(PotentialSolution ps, List<PotentialSolution> possibleTracks)
    {
        for (Track trytrack = Track.Empty + 1; trytrack < Track.MaxVal; trytrack++)
        {
            if (validMove(ps.nextSide, trytrack))
            {
                ps.SetCell(trytrack);
                possibleTracks.Add(ps);
            }
        }
        return tryNextTrack(ps, possibleTracks);
    }
```

The `PotentialSolution` class looks like this:

```
public class PotentialSolution
{
    public Track[,] board;
    public Side nextSide;
    public int h;
    public int w;
    static int cellsPerSide;
    static bool testing;
    static int minTracks;
    .....
    public void SetCell(Track t)
    {
        board[h, w] = t;
    }
}
```

So we are trying to make several copies of the `board` which only differ by which 'track' is placed in the current cell.
If I have a breakpoint at `possibleTracks.Add(ps)` then I can see by inspecting `ps` that the required cell contents is changing each time, as required.
But when the code reaches the next line (or the return statement), the cell content is the same in each member of the list (it's the last one that was added).
What I am doing wrong here? I have tried using an ArrayList and also a basic array instead, but get the same result. It's acting as though the `board` member is decared as static, but it's not.

[edit]

In response to those who suggested making copies of `ps`, you are correct and I had tried this before - but only tried single-stepping after the change and didn't run the full program (this method is used hundreds of times). When running the full program, making copies of `ps` certainly makes a difference to the result (although it's still not correct). The problem now, and why I didn't stick with using the copies, is that an added test still shows the list to contain the same versions of `ps`, even though the debugger has shown 2 or 3 different `tracks` being deployed:

```
    private PotentialSolution tryFirstTrack(PotentialSolution ps, List<PotentialSolution> possibleTracks)
    {
        for (Track trytrack = Track.Empty + 1; trytrack < Track.MaxVal; trytrack++)
        {
            if (validMove(ps.nextSide, trytrack))
            {
                PotentialSolution newps = new PotentialSolution(ps);
                newps.SetCell(trytrack);
                possibleTracks.Add(newps);

            }
        }
        // temporary test, can be removed
        if (possibleTracks.Count >= 2)
        {
            PotentialSolution ps1 = new PotentialSolution(possibleTracks.First());
            PotentialSolution ps2 = new PotentialSolution(possibleTracks.Last());
            if (ps1.GetCell() != ps2.GetCell())
            {
                // should always get here but never does
                int foo = 1;
            }
        }
        return tryNextTrack(ps, possibleTracks);
    }
```

By the way, `Track` and `nextSide` are just enum integers, they will be 0-6, and the list will contain 0,1,2,or 3 members, never more.

Comment: Initialize a new variable when adding to your list. When u update ps, its updated everywhere because of references

Comment: Actually, I'm having trouble to understand what is going on. It's a hard text to follow. =/

Comment: It's like if I put on a red shirt and make a dinner reservation, then put on a green shirt and make another dinner reservation and then put on a blue shirt and make yet another dinner reservation, the restaurant will show that the same person (me) is reserved three times, and when I show up, I'll still be wearing that final blue shirt.  You need to make a **copy** of your potential solution - and each copy will need its own Track[,] array.  (I'm assuming Track is a struct and has value semantics, not class semantics, because you are adding 1 to it, but might wanna check that too.)

Comment: @Wyck - great explanation, thanks. I tried making copies before (sorry, should have mentioned that) - please see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider giving the `PotentialSolution` type *value semantics* by making it a *struct* and implementing a `Clone` method, or a constructor that takes another `PotentialSolution` as an argument.  Also, to clone a 2D array **of value types**, call `Object.Clone()` and cast the result to `T[,]`.

When making a copy of your `PotentialSolution`, you'll need to make sure your clone your `board` array, because, in your case, each `PotentialSolution` keeps its own representation of the state of the `board`.

I feel like the critical part you're missing is how to shallow clone a 2D array, which in general,  is:

```
T[,] copy = (T[,])original.Clone();
```

**WARNING:** `Clone` creates a *shallow* copy of the array.  For value-types this copies the values of each element, so for your int-like "`Track`" type it does what you want, but for other readers who may be using reference-types (like classes) it does not clone each object referred to by each element of the array. The elements of the new array are just object references, and will still refer to the same objects referred to by the elements of the original array.  [See the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.clone?view=net-5.0#remarks).

Full example below that changes the middle cell of a 3x3 board from `A` to `B`.

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

public enum Track { A, B, C }
public enum Side { X, Y, Z }

public struct PotentialSolution
{
    public Track[,] board;
    public Side nextSide;
    public int h;
    public int w;
        
    public void SetCell(Track t)
    {
        board[h, w] = t;
    }

    public PotentialSolution(Track[,] board, Side nextSide, int h, int w)
    {
        this.board = (Track[,])board.Clone();
        this.nextSide = nextSide;
        this.h = h;
        this.w = w;
    }

    public PotentialSolution Clone()
    {
        return new PotentialSolution(board, nextSide, h, w);
    }

    // This `ToString` is provided for illustration only
    public override string ToString() 
    {
        var range0 = board.GetLength(0);
        var range1 = board.GetLength(1);
        var b = board;
        return string.Join(",",
            Enumerable.Range(0, range0)
                .Select(x => Enumerable.Range(0, range1)
                    .Select(y => b[x, y]))
                .Select(z => "[" + string.Join(",", z) + "]"));
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Track[,] someBoard = new Track[3, 3];
        PotentialSolution ps1 = new PotentialSolution(someBoard, Side.X, 1, 1);
        ps1.SetCell(Track.A);
        PotentialSolution ps2 = ps1.Clone();
        ps2.SetCell(Track.B);

        Console.WriteLine(ps1);
        Console.WriteLine(ps2);
    }
}
```

I'm filling in the blanks liberally, so please excuse any assumptions I have made that differ from your actual situation, because I have done so only to make this example self-contained.  My `ToString` implementation and its usage of `System.Linq` is not necessary; it's purely for the purposes of displaying the 2D array in my example.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding references to the same object: `ps` in `possibleTracks.Add(ps)`

You could add a constructor to `PotentialSolution` duplicating the class:

```
public class PotentialSolution
{
    public Track[,] board;
    public Side nextSide;
    public int h;
    public int w;
    static int cellsPerSide;
    static bool testing;
    static int minTracks;
    //.....
    public PotentialSolution()
    {
    }
    public PotentialSolution(PotentialSolution ps)
    {
        board = ps.board;
        nextSide = ps.nextSide;
        h = ps.h;
        w = ps.w;
    }
    //.....
```

Then use:

```
  private PotentialSolution tryFirstTrack(PotentialSolution ps, List<PotentialSolution> possibleTracks)
    {
        for (Track trytrack = Track.Empty + 1; trytrack < Track.MaxVal; trytrack++)
        {
            if (validMove(ps.nextSide, trytrack))
            {
                ps.SetCell(trytrack);
                possibleTracks.Add(new PotentialSolution(ps)); // duplicate object
            }
        }
        return tryNextTrack(ps, possibleTracks);
    }
```

This creates a new instance of the class each time it is added to the list.

Comment: first call ````SetCell```` on new instance then add it to the list.

Comment: @cly, This call is not needed. The same `ps` object is re-used throughout the process. I have edited to clarify.

Comment: Yes, correct. I tried making copies before (sorry, should have mentioned that) - please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

You always call `SetCell` on the same `ps` object you received as a parameter then add the same instance to the `possibleTracks` list. The result is: `possibleTrack` contains `ps` n times and because it is the same instance you used in each cycle it will have the last change you applied via `SetCell` call.

Not sure what you wanted to achieve but it looks you need a modified copy of `ps` in each cycle for adding to `possibleTrack` list. Making `PotentialSolution` a `struct` instead of `class` could be enough? Structs are copied in such a way but may hit your performance if `PotentialSolution` is big.

The `board` member will still generate the same problem, because despite `ps` will be copied but the `board` inside it will contain same `Track` references. The trick can be applied to `Track` too, but the performance issues may raise more.

Just implement a `Clone` on `PotentialSolution` to have fully detached instances of it, then call ````SetCell``` on cloned instance and add that instance to the list.

Comment: Your `struct` solution was completely valid. It was my first thought.

Comment: Can't easily make it a struct, it has lots of methods now :(